# How to save the translated language setting in my ionic 3 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ngx-translate

Iam using Ngx Translation to translate my app from EN to HI (hindi) everything works gr8 but when i close the app and restart it the app is translated back to english. Is their any way i can keep my changed language setting or any way to keep it stored as per the setting chose but the current user logged in?

Settings.html

```
<ion-item>
                    <ion-label>Change Language</ion-label>
                    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="language" (ionChange)="changeLanguage()" name="language" placeholder="Select Language">
                       <ion-option value="en" selected="true">English</ion-option>
                       <ion-option value="hi">Hindi</ion-option>
                    </ion-select>
                </ion-item>
```

settings.ts

```
changeLanguage()
{

   this.translateService.use(this.language);
}
```

i want to keep the changed language even if the app is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-save-the-translated-language-setting-in-the-app/172319/2?u=aditbharadwaj

the Answer to this question is using local storage to store the change value

```
changeLanguage()
{

   this.translateService.use(this.language);
   localStorage.setItem("myConfig", this.language);
}
And this to load (app.component.ts, first method or constructor):

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
     this.translateService.use(localStorage["myConfig"]);
});
```